# How to optionally skip several processing steps on Flux

Tags: java, option-type, flux, project-reactor

I have dynamic hot stream of data received from socket.
I need to check condition, and if the value matches, jump to step3 with new message.

```java
    final Flux<Msg> msgs = Flux.generate(receiver);

    final Flux<Msg> processed = msgs
        .map(this::checkCondition)  //step1
        .map(remote::doLongRunning) //optional step2
        .map(this::processFurther)  //step3
 ...

    public Msg checkCondition(Msg msg) {
        if(doCheck(msg)){
            //is there a way to jump to step3 here ?
            return new OtherMsg(msg, "someAdditionalData")) 
        } else{
            return msg
        }
    }
```

The only alternative I can think of - is splitting the Flux and assembling it back, is there any cleaner approach ?

```java
   final Flux<Msg> msgs = Flux.generate(receiver);

        final Flux<OtherMsg> checked = msgs
            .filter(this::doCheck) //step1
            .map(msg -> new OtherMsg(msg, "someAdditionalData"));

        final Flux<OtherMsg> unchecked = msgs
            .filter(msg -> !doCheck(msg)) //step1
            .map(remote::doLongRunning);  //optional step2

        Flux.merge(checked, unchecked)
            .map(this::processFurther)  //step3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *skip* a step, but you can use `flatMap()` with the ternary operator for a form of conditional branching instead:

```
final Flux<Msg> processed = msgs
        .flatMap(msg -> doCheck(msg)
            ? Mono.just(new OtherMsg(msg, "someAdditionalData")).map(remote::doLongRunning)
            : Mono.just(msg))
        .map(this::processFurther);
```

This way you can call any other method to manipulate the value in the first part of the ternary expression, and the second part will ensure it's bypassed if `doCheck()` returns false. `processFurther()` will be executed after the `flatMap()` call, so will always execute regardless.